# Long mail delivery time

Tags: postfix

My mail server took too long to deliver email, and from my mail log I found the delay value is high. Please guide me on how to reduce the time before queue manager. Thanks.

```
Jun 26 01:11:21 host postfix/smtpd[20826]: 3CEA53000CC631: client=localhost[127.0.0.1], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=abc
Jun 26 01:11:21 host postfix/cleanup[20831]: 3CEA53000CC631: message-id=<add28a0a5a90171cd5c2370cc604595e@example.com>
Jun 26 01:14:28 host postfix/qmgr[13870]: 3CEA53000CC631: from=<abc@example.com>, size=5929654, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 26 01:14:28 host postfix/pipe[21037]: 3CEA53000CC631: to=<test@gmail.com>, relay=dfilt, delay=191, delays=191/0.01/0/0.15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dfilt service)
Jun 26 01:14:28 host postfix/qmgr[13870]: 3CEA53000CC631: removed
Jun 26 01:19:30 host postfix/pickup[13869]: 22B883000CC637: uid=384 from=<abc@example.com>
Jun 26 01:19:30 host postfix/cleanup[20831]: 22B883000CC637: message-id=<10d18df692f53f7ac3b1966f74f468cc@example.com>
Jun 26 01:19:38 host postfix/qmgr[13870]: 22B883000CC637: from=<abc@example.com>, size=3926, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 26 01:19:40 host postfix/smtpd[20773]: connect from gateway[192.168.0.18]
Jun 26 01:19:41 host postfix/smtp[21607]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4002:c06::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Jun 26 01:19:42 host postfix/smtp[21607]: 22B883000CC637: to=<test@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.21.27]:25, delay=230, delays=226/0.01/3.2/0.55, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1498411182 z187si2453601ybb.86 - gsmtp)
Jun 26 01:19:42 host postfix/qmgr[13870]: 22B883000CC637: removed
```

Here is my postfix configuration:

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = mail.example.com
mydomain = example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
mynetworks_style = host
relayhost = 
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
home_mailbox = Maildir/
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION" DEFAULT=$HOME/Maildir/ MAILDIR=$HOME/Maildir
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks.regexp
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mbl-body-deny
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
invalid_hostname_reject_code = 554
multi_recipient_bounce_reject_code = 554
non_fqdn_reject_code = 554
relay_domains_reject_code = 554
unknown_address_reject_code = 554
unknown_client_reject_code = 554
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 554
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 554
unknown_relay_recipient_reject_code = 554
unknown_sender_reject_code = 554
unknown_virtual_alias_reject_code = 554
unknown_virtual_mailbox_reject_code = 554
unverified_recipient_reject_code = 554
unverified_sender_reject_code = 554
empty_address_recipient = MAILER-DAEMON
message_size_limit = 15000000
mailbox_size_limit = 620000000
local_transport = local
notify_classes = 2bounce,resource,software
bounce_notice_recipient = postmaster
default_process_limit = 200
queue_run_delay = 600s
delay_warning_time = 12h
smtpd_banner = dolphineng.com ESMTP
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 6
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mailserverreq.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/mailserver.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_sender_login_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/login_maps.pcre
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_sender_login_mismatch,
    reject_unlisted_sender,
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
    permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =  
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    reject_unknown_address,
    reject_unlisted_recipient,
    reject_invalid_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/recipient_checks.pcre,
    check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    check_client_access pcre:/etc/postfix/fqrdns.pcre
    reject_sender_login_mismatch,
    reject_non_fqdn_sender,    
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net,
    reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com,
    reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org,
    permit
smtpd_data_restrictions =
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        permit
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_bcc_maps
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
smtpd_restriction_classes = local_only
local_only = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/local_domain, reject
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtp_data_xfer_timeout = 600s
```

Comment: Do you have well configured ipv6 address on your server?

Comment: @learn2code - I don't think 12 seconds is too long. That said, the only problem in your error log is the failed IPv6 lookup, see here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293800/i-dont-get-ipv6-why-cannot-i-ping-ipv6-google-com

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy i didn't configure anything for ipv6 yet and currently it's default settings.

Comment: @JoeBrailsford I have another old mail server and the delay value is below 50. I have checked on the old mail server and found ipv6's configuration is default too.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's rehearse what the values in `delays=` means (from [`delay_logging_resolution_limit`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#delay_logging_resolution_limit)):

> The format of the `delays=a/b/c/d` logging is as follows:
>
> - a = time from message arrival to last active queue entry
> - b = time from last active queue entry to connection setup
> - c = time in connection setup, including DNS, EHLO and STARTTLS
> - d = time in message transmission

In your examples, only the `a` is increased, meaning the delay comes during the connection from the SASL authenticated client. Everything after the message arrives from the client is happening fast. This can lead to a conclusion that the problem may not be in server configuration, but in client connection.

The sample from your logs contains delivery of two separate messages.

1. Lines beginning with `3CEA53000CC631`: `delays=191/0.01/0/0.15`, `size=5929654`

   Here, the message size might be the cause. The upload speed seems to be around 31 kBps, which is plausible with customer DSL, if there's something else uploaded simultaneously.
2. Lines beginning with `22B883000CC637`: `delays=226/0.01/3.2/0.55`, `size=3926`

   As the size is now considerably lower, we can't blame the upload bandwidth alone anymore.

   We can see that even when the message was first tried to deliver forward with failing IPv6 connection `[2607:f8b0:4002:c06::1b]:25: Network is unreachable` and then again successfully on IPv4, the delay `c` has only increased by 3 seconds. You should either fix or disable your IPv6 connection, but that isn't the main cause for the delay.

For further investigation see what happens during *mail user agent* MUA connection.

Comment: I'm using Roundcube webmail. Whenever I compose an email especially email with attachment then it will take quite long time to deliver, and sometimes it will return the request time out error but the message will still appear in mail queue.